# Validate parts of a Symfony form based on other parts of the form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.5

I have a rather large form to build, and certian parts of the form need to be validated when a particular option is selected, and only if that option is selected.  How can I make sure to skip those validations if I don't need them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a "huge" validation method, then into validation itself, check for "selected options": if there are some, check for "sub-condition"

Something like

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert; 
/**
 *
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"isValid"})
 */
class ObjectRelatedToYourForm
{
[...]
  public function isValid(ExecutionContext $context)
  {
    if ($this->optionOneSelected) {
      //perform controls and add violation in case of failure
    }
    if ($this->optionTwoSelected) {
      //perform controls and add violation in case of failure
    }
  }
}
```